# NSDictionary Method Return Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I have A Method Returns NSDictionary its defined in FrameWork Library

```
- (NSDictionary*) getApplicationConfig
  {         
        ...................................
   }
```

Now i want to call this method in my App delegate  , can anyone suggest me the right way to to it.

NSDictionary *abc = getApplcationConfig();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the Apple doc for [NSDictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html), you have several options.

You can either use instance method `[[NSDictionary alloc]initWithDictionary:[someInstance getApplicationConfig]]` or class method `[NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[someInstance getApplicationConfig]]`

Answer (score 0):

Start by reading an [Objective-C tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/d/learn_objectivec/)
It should be something like this

```
NSDictionary *abc = [someObject getApplicationConfig];
```